# Infinite commas after insertion sort in js

Tags: javascript

I don't know why infinite commas, are printed while executing Insertion Sort in Javascript.
So I can't run it in browser, though I tested it in jsbin, link is [here.](http://jsbin.com/EDoPUGUG/2/edit)

```
var ids = [3, 4, 8, 5, 33, 56, 23, 67, 231, 12, 43, 50];
var j, i;
for (j = 2; j <= ids.length; j++) {
    var selectn = ids[j];
    i = j - 1;
    while (i > 1 && ids[i] > selectn) {
        ids[i + 1] = ids[i];
        i = i - 1;
    }
    ids[i + 1] = selectn;
}
```

Please tell why it is so, and how I can correct it?

Comment: Always include the code in your question. Please also explain what the code is supposed to do. To debug the problem yourself, [learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), set breakpoints, use `console.log`, inspect the variables and see if they really have the values you expect them to have.

Comment: I will keep it on my mind, thnx.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're not using JavaScript `sort()`?

Comment: I like to make functions, for having strong foundation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `ids.length` keeps changing as you modify your array.

Cache the length first (`var l = ids.length`) and change your loop to `for( j=2; j<l; j++)`

Comment: I was not able to figure out source of error for infinite commas, now I got it! thanx.